# Query dynamodb for text search?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am looking to optimize the dynamodb operations i.e removing scans and use queries to fetch data fastly.

Table Data:

```
itemId  itemName  itemOwners

hash1   abc       [user1, user2]
hash2   abcd      [user1, user3]
hash3   xyz       [user2, user3]
```

I have to do the item search using an item name.
Right now, we scan the whole table.

```
  let getItems = {
    TableName: ItemsTable,
    FilterExpression: 'contains (#itemName, :searchValue)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#itemName': 'itemName' },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':searchValue': searchValue },
  };
  let items = await docClient.scan(getItems).promise();
```

We then filter the items result if the itemOwners contains the userId for the searching user.

I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this search query with dynamodb?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do a `contains` in DynamoDB without it being a filter condition. DynamoDB is not really designed for full text search. However, there is a way to do some degree of text search capabilities from DynamoDB. I'm not suggesting you should, but you can. Basically you create a record for each word/item combination you want to include in your search. This doesn't allow for partial word matches, but it is a way to get full word matching. That, of course, requires pre-processing all your data to make it available for search. If you decide to go this route I would recommend using DynamoDB streams to manage updating the search data. Every time an item is inserted/updated/deleted from the database you can run a lambda to update the search records for that item. Again, not suggesting you should do this, but you can.

I would recommend investigating CloudSearch as an alternative to this.